# Задачи на закрепление JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Хотелось бы несколько задач на JS, лучше будет всё в одном, но можно и в разброс. Задачи нужны средней сложности. Но вообще лучше посоветуйте книгу, где есть каждая глава с задачами. Или просто задачник)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как такового задачника нету, есть только задания по [лабораторным работам в универах](http://www.twirpx.com/files/informatics/languages/web/labs/)

А так решайте задачи поставленные в вопросах форумов, да и задайтесь целью написать web-приложение (сайт), уверяю задач будет много)

Comment: Эти лабораторные я уже решил)  
Они только на формулы и знание мат. части.  
Сейчас думаю над проектиком)

Comment: Ну не все на мат.часть, у нас к примеру были лабы по работе со временем, а также вывода сообщений, создание функций, работа со страницей (изменение содержимого, фона), обработка событий по нажатию кнопок и т.д)

Answer (score 2):

Хотите задачу? ок - напишите калькулятор, чтобы закрепить работа с DOM'om напишите простенький сайт исключительно сресдтвами JS.

т.е.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <script type="text/javascript">
         // вот сдесь вот програмно создавайте страничку :)
     </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```